# Rails query in controller with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have the following relationships set up in my models for Festivals, Categories, Submissions and Curators (users).

- Festival has many categories. Each category has one Festival.
- Each category has one or more curators (a user) and curators could have more than one category.
- Submissions have one category and one festival (through it's category).
- "current_user" is the user that is logged in
- "current_festival" is the one festival that is currently taking new submissions

When a curator (a user) is logged in and they look at the index of submissions. They should only see submissions for which they are curator (through category). I'm stumped on how to generate the proper list of submissions. Here is what is in the controller now:

```
def index
  @submissions = current_festival.submissions.all
end
```

This would return all the submissions for the current festival, not just from the categories that the current_user is the curator. What I want is something like this, but I don't know the proper syntax:

```
def index
  @categories = current_user.categories.where(festival_id: current_festival.id)
  @submissions = current_festival.submissions.where( category_id: "one of the @categories" )
end
```

Any ideas what the proper syntax would be?

Comment: In 2nd query you want to fetch submissions where category_id lies in @categories that return from 1st query...right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all the submission that belongs to category which are created by current_user

```
def index
  category_ids = current_user.categories.where(festival_id: current_festival.id).collect(&:id)
  @submissions = current_festival.submissions.where(category_id: category_ids)
end
```